# Interrupting the Monitor() command with a DTMF press

Tags: asterisk, sip

The asterisk `Record` command allows for stopping the recording when the pound(`#`) key is pressed.

I'm looking for an equivalent for the `Monitor()` command. i.e. that audio stops streaming to a file if the pound key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

What you searching calling "one touch monitor"

See features.conf options

```
automon => *1                   ; One Touch Record a.k.a. Touch Monitor 
;-- Make sure to set the W and/or w option in the Dial() or Queue() app call!
```

You also can do custom feature and use in it MixMonStop.

Comment: This seems to be useful to start recording (by calling the `Monitor` command) with a DTMF. But I'm looking for an equivalent of "press `#` to stop the recording", that exists in the `Record()` command, but not in the `Monitor()` command. Did I understand your suggestion correctly, that it will only allow starting the `Monitor` command, but not stopping it?